# How to install GUI on Ubuntu Server 12.04 from USB stick without internet connection

Tags: server, system-installation, gui

How to install GUI on Ubuntu Server 12.04 from USB stick without internet connection

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just re-install the whole thing with Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you have ubuntu desktop on the usb. Or else you have to visit http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/12.04/release/ and download the ubuntu-desktop image for the your architecture. And then create a boot usb.

Firstly you have to remove (or comment them by adding a # in front) all lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` so you can call

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Without getting any errors.

Once you have the usb connected you can add the deb src lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` by using the apt-cdrom tool.

Description on how to use apt-cdrom can be seen here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom

Basically it boils down to these commands.

```
sudo apt-cdrom ident 
sudo apt-cdrom -d "your-usb-mount-point" -r
```

Once you have the correct apt lines you can must install the `ubuntu-desktop` package in order to get the gui.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't worked

Comment: Which part didn't work ?